# Installing bash commands in docker to use in airflow

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile, airflow

I am trying to use a bash operator to unzip a file within an airflow DAG. This is the task that I am trying to use:

```
    unzip_dataset_task = BashOperator(
        task_id="unzip_dataset_task",
        bash_command=f"unzip -o {path_to_local_home}/{dataset_zip} -d {path_to_local_home}",
    )
```

Because os does not automatically come with the "unzip" command, I included this line within my DockerFile to download it:

```
RUN apt-get install unzip
```

However, I keep on getting this error in my logs:

> airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Bash command failed. The command returned a non-zero exit code 127.

From what I can gather, this means that "command is not found", or that Docker can't use the unzip bash command. I am confused because my DockerFile has explicit instructions to install unzip, so I am not sure why I am receiving this error.

Does anyone see where I went wrong?

Comment: What happens when you change the command to `apt-get install unzip -y`?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I included the -y in the DockerFile but unfortunately I still get the same error

Comment: Hm... do you evenn use a debian based distro? Also, try running your docker build with the `--progress=plain` flag